# How to get value from RecycleAdapter and set to MainActivity Text?

Tags: java, android, textview

My Adapter Code looks like :

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        GetSet getSet = allData.get(position);
        holder.tvId.setText(getSet.getId().toString());
        holder.tvName.setText(getSet.getName());

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        @BindView(R.id.tvId)
        TextView tvId;

        @BindView(R.id.tvName)
        TextView tvName;
```

I have `textview` in `MainActivity`, my question is how to get value/text id and name to set in `textview`?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have label in Activity and you wanted to pass the updated string to Activity. See the following suggestion

**Adapter**

```
//create an interface in adapter
public interface LabelChangeListener {
    void onLabelChanged(String text);
}

//create a method inside adapter
public void setLabelChangeListener(LabelChangeListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

//optional: create this method inside adapter
public void updateActivityLabel() {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onLabelChanged("this is update");
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
//from activity 
adapter.setLabelChangeListener(new LabelChangeListener() {
    void onLabelChanged(String text) {
        lblYourTextView.setText(text);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but no change :( still same, can u give me more ex?

Comment: here man [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273614/change-value-recycleview-adapter-and-save-it-to-textview-in-mainactivity)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Id or name of an Item on Recyclerview You can write a public function in Adapter Code like this:

```
public GetSet getGetSetItem(int position){
  return allData.get(position);
}
```

Then you call in `MainActivity` like this: `adapter.getGetSetItem(1).getId();` or `adapter.getGetSetItem(1).getName();`

Comment: thanks, how about with custom text? so there is no getter, only holder.tvName.setText("My Name"); how to call in MainActivity?

Comment: If there is a custom textView, I believe that you set default text that you know or a text depend on current item. So, you can do it again for textview in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing, you can use an api of recycler view to retrieve view holder item:

```
findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
```