# Change value recycleview.adapter and save it to textview in mainactivity?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I change the value from recycleview.adapter, i want to set it the value to textview in mainactivity, how to do it?

it will be like this,
[image: sample]

the recycle data retreive from my json, so it will be random and many data,
when I change or add the value of "total win" to more than "0", the textview  at bottom will be appear, and "total all" will count from data I add, when its done, I want to send the "result" value to next activity or post and save it to mysql dbase,

here my code of MainActivity :

```
    ...

private List<Details> listDetails = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerAdapter viewAdapter;

@BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    viewAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, listDetails);
   RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
   recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
   recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);

    getMyData();

}
    ...

private void getMyData() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConfig.URL_MAIN)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
        ...
    });

    ...
```

My RecycleAdapter code :

```
    ...

private Context context;
private List<Details> listDetails;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Details> listDetails) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDetails = listDetails;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Details getSet = listDetails.get(position);

    holder.tvName.setText(getSet.getName());
    holder.numberPickerTotalWin.setValueChangedListener(new ValueChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(int value, ActionEnum action) {

             Toast.makeText(context, position + value + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listDetails.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    @BindView((R.id.nP))
    NumberPicker numberPickerTotalWin;

    @BindView(R.id.tvName)
    TextView tvName;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to increment the value of "total win"? What view are you using to tell it to add 1, or 2 or what ever number? Also, if you want to add a number to a number currently displayed inside of a TextView. You first need to get the text from the TextView and them convert it to an integer using Integer.valueOf() passing in the text from your TextView and then add that value to your incrementer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code

YourActivity   ... implements RecyclerViewItemClick

```
     private List<Details> listDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        private RecyclerAdapter viewAdapter;

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        viewAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, listDetails, this);
       RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
       recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
       recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);

        getMyData();

    }
        ...

    private void getMyData() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConfig.URL_MAIN)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
            ...
        });
```

> RecyclerViewAdapter

```
private RecyclerViewItemClick mListener;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Details> listDetails, RecyclerViewItemClick listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDetails = listDetails;
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v, mListener);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Details getSet = listDetails.get(position);

        holder.tvName.setText(getSet.getName());
        holder.numberPickerTotalWin.setValueChangedListener(new ValueChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(int value, ActionEnum action) {

                 Toast.makeText(context, position + value + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listDetails.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        @BindView((R.id.nP))
        NumberPicker numberPickerTotalWin;

        @BindView(R.id.tvName)
        TextView tvName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mListener != null){
//you can access to the current position if you want -> getLayoutPosition()
              mListener.yourMethod();

}
        }

public interface RecyclerViewItemClick { 
   void yourMethod();

}
    }
```

Comment: nothing happen, still no change :( how to pass the value to text?

Comment: your question is not very clear, please try to put the full code(activity and adapter)