# Calculate all value from recycler adapter viewholder textlistener?

Tags: android, listener, android-recyclerview, textwatcher

My Recycle code :

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    @BindView(R.id.tvName) TextView tvName;
    @BindView(R.id.tvRank) TextView tvRank;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    tvName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //blabla
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //blabla
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //blabla
            }
        });
}
```

The result from recycleview above will be like this :

```
-----------------
Jack           10
-----------------
Jason          14
-----------------
Rony           11
-----------------
```

I want to calculate all value from "rank" when textview "rank" is on change, it is possible? I have done to try, but only can one value, how to calculate all value? so, the result what i want is

```
Jack, Rony, Jason = 35
```

Comment: Can u please explain more. What did you mean when u say "I want to calculate all value" ?

Comment: All value is very vague. If you could explain exactly what you want and what you mean it would help incredibly. But if you are trying to calculate some numeric value (I hope, you can get the text form the TextView and convert it to a int or a long or any interger type using the valueOf(...) methods of Long, Integer, Double, Float and Short. With that being said, each of those objects also have methods for converting their current data type to another. Further more, you need to make sure that your TextView only holds number or else you'll get an exception.

Comment: @MuratGuc edited question :)

Comment: @WadeWilson yea, can u please answer my question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273614/change-value-recycleview-adapter-and-save-it-to-textview-in-mainactivity) its same with this question, but different code, I use value int

Comment: View my answer, it should guide you to finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is iterate over every value inside of the RecyclerView's Adapter data set, you'd access the each rank value and add it to some int variable that stores the total. Once you've added all of the totals return the value. Example:

```
public class RankAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    public static class RankData {
        public String name;
        public int rank;
    }
    // This gets set either in a constructor or a setter method.
    private ArrayList<RankData> rankDatas;

    public int getTotalRank() {
        int totalRank = 0;
        for(RankData data : rankDatas){
            totalRank += data.rank;
        }
        return totalRank;
    }

    @Override
    public RankViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return new RankViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkable_item_layout_view, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RankViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RankData data = rankDatas.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(data.name);
        holder.rank.setText(data.rank);
    }

    public class RankViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView rank;

         public RankViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(id.nameTxtVw);
            rank = itemView.findViewById(id.rankTxtVw);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're are storing your rank as a value as a string you can convert it into int by doing the following:

```
int rankInt = Integer.valueOf(rankStr).intValue();
```

And you'd then add rankInt to the 'totalRank' variable like above.